# Missing ActiveRecord methods (find_by) for object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to do an assignment which requires me to create and save an ActiveRecord within my Model class, and then return it.  The rspec is expecting to use the find_by method to verify this.  Here's my Model:

## -----------------------

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :id, :username, :password_digest, :created_at, :updated_at
after_initialize :add_user

def initialize(attributes={})
    @username = attributes[:username]
    @password_digest = attributes[:password_digest]
    super
end

def add_user
    self[:username] = @username
    self[:password_digest] = @password_digest
    self.save
    self[:id] = self.id
end
end
```

## ----------------

If I do User.new(params), the record is in fact stored properly to the DB.  But, the find_by method is missing for the returned object.  So, rspec fails.  I have looked everywhere but can't seem to find the solution.  I am a noob, so sorry if the answer is obvious and I can't see it.

Comment: Show the failing RSpec example and the error message, please.

Comment: ActiveRecord objects don't have a `find_by` method... `find_by` is a class method.

Can you show the RSpec test?

Comment: This some pretty weird code - for example having User.new save the record is very unusual.

Comment: So, simply getting rid of all that insanity in the Class model for User except for initializing the username and password fields in the initialize method, then in the assignment.rb file just calling new with the attributes followed by a save, the rspec test worked.  I believe I was just way overthinking this!

Answer (score 0):

You say

> If I do User.new(params), the record is in fact stored properly to the DB. But, the find_by method is missing for the returned object

This is expected behavior. Hopefully you understand by now the difference between class and instance methods. The main important point is that query methods such as `find_by` are not made available to model instances. If you do something like `user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])`, you're calling the `find_by` class method on the `User` model.

There are a number of methods like `where`, `order`, `limit`, etc. that are defined in `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods` - these are made available to `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and your model class. Most of these methods will return `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects, which is why they're chainable, e.g.

```
User.where(params).order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)
```

However `find_by` is an exception - it returns a model instance so you can't continue to query on the results.  In summary `User.new(params)` returns an instance of the model which doesn't have `find_by` available